# how to select the radio button using key ENTER in the keyboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

In the above image. I wanted to search the text depends on the category. i wanted to select the radio button using keyboard for to select the category.

this my key listener coming from controller. SELECT is referred to the key ENTER in the keyboard.
I have tried the below code, using radio button ID, but it selects the 1st radio button.
can anyone Help me...

```
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.SELECT:                
    if (searchPageRadioButtonCtrl) {
       document.getElementById("searchFilternames").checked = true;
    }
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.BACK:
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.RIGHT:
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.LEFT:
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.DOWN:
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.UP:
  break;
```

And my html where the Radio button is generated. id of the radio button is "searchFilternames"

```
<div id="searchCategory">
  <div id="searchFilter" ng-repeat="item in searchFilters">
    <input id="searchFilternames"type="radio" ng-model="selectedFilter.name"
       value="{{item.name}}" ng-class="{'selectedRadioButtonborder': isRadioFocussed($index)}"
       yo-attr="{html : 'item.name'}"/><span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the method for radio button.

```
$scope.isRadioFocussed = function (index){
        if (index == searchPageRadioButtonCtrl) return true;
        else return false;
    };
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
 in the above image, i need to take controller to next radio button, for i am using searchPageRadioButtonCtrl

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSWML.png

Comment: What is `searchPageRadioButtonCtrl`? Where are you setting it?

Comment: searchPageRadioButtonCtrl, it is refering for index, i need to increase the if i want to got rightindex

Comment: Try the answer I posted if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

First things is you have to add `name` attribute to your radios to make them mutually exclusive and then you can use below code

```
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.SELECT:                

   var radios = document.getElementById('searchFilter').getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
   {
       var radio = radios[i]
       if(radio.type=='radio')
       {
            if(radio.checked)
            {

                if(radios.length>i+1)
                {
                    var radioNext = radios[i+1];
                    radioNext.checked=true;
                    break;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     radios[0].checked=true;
                     break;
                  }

               }
           }
      }
break;
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLp3jgad/1/)**

Comment: sir i understood ur code, but what my situation is, in my image if my ALL is selected then if i move my controller to movies, the All should be highlighted only.

Comment: `the All should be highlighted only.` what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sir in my project, i am searching depends on category, If i wanted to search the Movies category. 1st i need to check the Movies button then i pass my controller to text field, i ill type some text, then i will move on to search button. For remote i am doing this one sir.

Comment: That ALL category radio button sir.